# Nickel salts from hypochlorites

Tags: transition-metals, oxidation-state, catalysis, halogens

(JUST A HEADS UP I’m 15 years old and new to chemistry) So I was recently looking around the house looking for products that I can extract chemicals from and I found a bottle of cleaning Vinegar ( 5% acetic acid), so I decided to make some acetate compounds, but when I first started I thought it would be a simple 1 step synthesis. I was wrong. I soon realized you must have hydrogen peroxide and acetic acid to make zink and copper Acetate.

So I tried making nickel acetate, with no luck. So then I tried to make nickel chloride knowing this new hydrogen peroxide step. I took a pure nickel sheet and put it in a beaker then added calcium hypochlorite and hydrogen peroxide. And it worked! The solution turned light green over a few hours, and it had a gas being produced. And also a black Precipitate which was most likely nickel oxide (I filtered the precipitate off before taking the picture)

But just to check myself I tried to find this process online, to no avail. So now I’m wondering if I did something wrong and got the wrong product or no one does it through this process. If you can check my process to make sure it’s possible and I didn’t waste my time I would Appreciate it. Thanks in advance.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: The solution is actually green. I had some UV lights off to the side for a different project that made it look blue. But I turned those off. And I also replaced the nickel strip for a nickel coin to be 100% shure it was infact nickel and not zink or some other Metal.

Comment: A US nickel is 25% nickel and 75% copper.

Comment: I’ll go find some more nickel strips

Answer (score 1):

Your result is surprising, for the following reasons : 1) Nickel compounds and ions are mainly green. And you say your solution is blue. 2) When treated by hypochlorite ions, Nickel will produce a black precipitate of $\ce{Ni_2O_3}$, which is not what you got . 3) You obtain a solution without any precipitate, although the hypochlorite solution is always basic, which must produce a Nickel Hydroxyde precipitate. 4) The only possibility to have a blue solution with Nickel, is adding ammonia $\ce{NH_3}$, which produces a blue Nickel-Ammonia complex in solution. So my question : Are you sure that you have taken pure Nickel in the beginning ? Other question : With this method you will obtain a lot of calcium chloride with a small amount of nickel (or copper ?) compound.